# How can I install Realtek Wifi Driver in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

I have plugged in **USB 2.0 Wireless 802.11N Adapter** in my **Ubuntu 20.04LTS Desktop**. I have got a driver disk with my purchased Adapter. It has a folder of Linux driver. I can't install it.
So it is showing - **No Wi-fi Adapter Found!**

I have read their Release note: Check it here
[Release Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAINN.png)

It is showing it supports only

```
Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.6.6)
```

But I have checked with **`uname -a`** command and found the following result:

```
Linux elliyaspc 5.4.0-38-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 8 14:14:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From **`lsusb`** command -

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2e04:c022  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After executing **`install.sh`** file, I am getting this errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xQA7.png)

I need to know - is it possible to install this Adapter in my PC? If yes, how?

Please help me.

Comment: It is possible, but it is a wrong driver. This won't build. Please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/c022/' RS=` command.

Comment: `T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(&gt;ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2e04 ProdID=c022 Rev=ff.ff
S:  Manufacturer=MediaTek
S:  Product=Nokia 1
S:  SerialNumber=FRTBA80314752381
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=03 Driver=rndis_host
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=rndis_host`

Comment: FYI: My PC is now connected with Nokia 1 with USB tethering.

Comment: Hm. This is not the dongle. Was it inserted when you ran `lsusb`? Maybe that one `1005:b128`? We need to find out what is the chip there.

Comment: It is - 

`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub`

Comment: No, this is a hub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109484/discussion-between-elliyas-ahmed-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 2):

First run `sudo apt update`

then install using following command

```
sudo apt install gcc make build-essential git linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

For detailed references check [here](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/12/20/how-to-install-realtek-wifi-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-lts/).

To overcome the issue occurring due to install.sh follow [this](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=13755671#p13755671) solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

In my driver it tells to run the install.sh file and I did it. But it is showing 2 errors: 

Check the question description. I have updated the errors.

Comment: @ElliyasAhmed check http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=13755671#p13755671

Comment: Follow these forums as well for solutions, 
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=94495 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2270233